# Elasticsearch replacing cross_fields with combined field and fuzzy

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an index which was previously searching a few fields such as this:

```
 "query":{
         "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {
                  "term":{
                     "eventvisibility":"public"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "should":[
               {
                  "multi_match":{
                     "query":"keyword",
                     "fields":[
                        "eventname",
                        "venue.name",
                        "venue.town"
                       
                     ],
                     "type":"cross_fields",
                     "minimum_should_match":"3<80%"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "match":{
                     "eventdescshort":{
                        "query":"keyword",
                        "minimum_should_match":"2<80%"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match":1
         }
      }
```

This works, but often fails due to spelling mistakes, etc with letters left off the keyword or transposed.

So I was hoping to implement fuzzy searching, As this doesn't work with cross_fields, I created a new field in the index:

```
        "mappings": {
            "event": {
                "properties": {
                   
                 "basic_search": {
                    "type": "text", 
                    "analyzer": "nameanalyzer"
                  },
                  "eventname":{
   
                        "type": "text",
                        "copy_to": "basic_search" ,
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": "nameanalyzer"
                    },
  "venue": {
                        "properties": {
                           
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "copy_to": "basic_search" ,
                                "fields": {
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                },
                                "analyzer": "nameanalyzer"
                            },
  
                     ...snip (all fields previosouly in cross_fields now have copy_to: basic_search) ...
}
```

And our analyzer is as follows:

```
"nameanalyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "stop",
                                "english_possessive_stemmer",
                                "english_minimal_stemmer",
                                "synonym",
                                "asciifolding",
                                "word_delimiter"
                            ],
                            "char_filter": "html_strip",
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
```

I've now run a test search, as follows:

```
{
    "query": {
        
                    "fuzzy": {
                        "basic_search": {
                            "value": "carers fair"
                           
                        }
                    }
                
    }
```

However, this is not giving me any matches at all.

I just get:

```
                                "type": "MatchNoDocsQuery",
                                "description": "MatchNoDocsQuery(\"empty BooleanQuery\")",
```

I know I can't see the contents of the `basic_search` field in _source, so how can I debug and know why this isn't matching?

Comment: Just in case you don't know query -> fuzzy doesn't analyze input text before doing a fuzzy search. try {
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "basic_search": {
        "query": "carers fair",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
       }
     }
   }
}

Comment: That's fixed it @SahilGupta feel free to pop as an answer!

Comment: Done .. Please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuzzy query don't analyze text before searching. Usage of the same should be avoided.

Excerpt from [ES Doc](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search) below :

> fuzzy query: The elasticsearch fuzzy query type should generally be avoided. Acts much like a term query. Does not analyze the query text first.

**Please try below query:**

```
  {
   "query":{
      "match":{
         "basic_search":{
            "query":"carers fair",
            "fuzziness":"AUTO"
         }
      }
   }
```